# How to convert a .doc file to PDF using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am writing code in Matlab which performs some calculations and writes out a report with tables and results in .doc format. I want to save the generated .doc report as a PDF or non-editable word format so that the report becomes unedited. I am using the `WritetoWordFromMatlab()` function for writing out the files.

I am looking for a command using `actxserver` which will save my file as a PDF. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: What are your code and problem

Comment: This is totally a programming question - it's about automating Office from Matlab using the ActiveX API. You may find it a distasteful thing to do, but it's programming, and the type that actually pops up in industry.

Comment: This question is currently being discussed [on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177441/why-was-this-question-about-matlab-closed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Office 2007 or 2010, you can use the `Document.ExportAsFixedFormat` method, passing `wdExportFormatPDF` as the `ExportFormat` argument. Fire up Word using `actxserver` in Matlab, have it open your .doc file, and write out the .pdf with `ExportAsFixedFormat`. Or fiddle with `writetowordfrommatlab` to save it to PDF directly.

Here's the doco on `ExportAsFixedFormat`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb256835%28v=office.12%29.aspx.

Here is a sample:

```
filename = fullfile(pwd, 'myfile.docx');
pdf_filename = fullfile(pwd, 'myfile.pdf');

% Create COM server
actx_word = actxserver('Word.Application');
actx_word.Visible = true;
% Open existing document
word_handle = invoke(actx_word.Documents,'Open',filename);

% Save as PDF
invoke(word_handle,'ExportAsFixedFormat',pdf_filename,'wdExportFormatPDF');            

% Close the window
invoke(word_handle,'Close');            
% Quit Word
invoke(actx_word,'Quit');            
% Close Word and terminate ActiveX
delete(actx_word);
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew.. That did it.. I gave the value 17 for the format and there came my pdf!!.. wow!.. thanks a lot..